# Test environment variables for CircleCI with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, continuous-integration, circleci

How can I set secrets.yml for test environment for CircleCI with Rspec? My secrets.yml is not on git.

When I run my tests on CircleCI, they fail with error:

`ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked out for me:

1. Create config/secrets.ci.yml with test environment variables.
2. Add circle.yml to the root directory:

circle.yml

```
machine:
  ruby:
    version:
      2.2.2

dependencies:
  override:
    - mv config/secrets.ci.yml config/secrets.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [CircleCI Environment Variables](https://circleci.com/docs/environment-variables#setting-environment-variables-for-all-commands-without-adding-them-to-git). This would allow you to load in secret info without it being in your repository or file system at all.

Not to mention that the AWS CLI will automatically [read those variables from the environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-environment) if they are present.